# Can not send both files and objects within a form

Tags: forms, asp.net-core, multipart

Hello i was wondering how could you send both  a `POCO` and `files` within a form.
My problem is twofold:

- 1.So far when i acess the `Request.Form.Files[0]` and copy it in a file i get a `0kb` file.
- If i want to get the `MyPoco` object from my form when i use the `[FromBody]` as a parameter to my method i get a `415` not supported type.

**Form**

```
<form id="createForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:8300/api/create">

<input type="text" bind="@model.Name"/>//some binding here
<input type="text" bind="@model.Id"/> //some binding...

<input type="file"/>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("api/create")]
        public async Task<long> CreateAsync([FromBody] MyPoco poco) { //getting error 415 when using the FromBody 
            try {

                MyPoco poc = poco;
                string path = Path.Combine(
                    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), 
                    "file.csv"); //copy the input file -> getting 0kb file
                FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
                await this.Request.Form.Files[0].CopyToAsync(stream);
                return 3;
            } catch (Exception) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

**P.S** The syntax of binding is `blazor` but it is unimportant in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `[FromBody]`, it will instruct the ModelBinder to read the whole payload and then serialize it as an instance of `MyPoco`.

To acheive your goals, you could declare your action method as below :

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public IActionResult Test(MyPoco myPoco,IFormFile myfile){
     // now you get the myfile file and the myPoco 
}
```

and then send  fields with the complete names :

```
<form id="createForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/api/SampleData/Test">

    <input name="MyPoco.Name" type="text" bind="@model.Name" />
    <input name="MyPoco.Id" type="text" bind="@model.Id" />

    <input name="myfile" type="file" />
    <button type="submit">submit this form</button>
</form>
```

a screenshot of demo :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response.However it did not work until i added a custom-made `multipart` deserializer.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Strangely,  the above code works for me by default . Have you customed anything else?

Comment: I kept getting `415` error with unsupported media type for `multipart` ContentType until i added a custom `InputFormatter` in my `services.AddMvc(options=>options.InputFormatters.Add(MyCustomFormatter))`